# Navigation drawer android activity stack

Tags: android

I have an application with a navigation drawer.
Every item starts a new activity using

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), That.class);
```

The root activity of mine is included in the drawer. So it happens that users click on several items in the drawer, thus growing the activity stack and that contains multiple instances of what i think should be the root activity. See pic

[image: Setting the sails of fail]

It would be even better if the activity stack never reached a depth > 2. I could have A as root and whenever user clicks B and then C, stack would look like

```
B :: A :: Bottom
```

Suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Late answer, but late is better than never.   I've handled this problem a couple of ways.  In one app, my Activity A was really my main screen. I set that as "android:launchMode="singleTop" in my manifest.  You have to set a newIntent() override, and when invoking that class you have to set some flags:             "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);"

Comment: I'm using a different pattern on another app. In this case, each item in the NavDrawer when clicked I set the current  "activity.finish()" before invoking the item pressed. And in each activity, I override onFinish to check if the task "isTaskRoot()" and if so, I fire up my main page again.  In either case, my activity stack is kept pruned and the user need not hit the back button multiple times to get out